# Errors compiling phonegap app in iOS with plugin GAPlugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have installed the plugin **github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin** to use google analytics for my **phonegap 3.4** app but I can't get it compile in iOS.

I get the next errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      anon in GoogleAnalytics.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      anon in GoogleAnalytics.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      anon in GoogleAnalytics.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      anon in GoogleAnalytics.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I have searched about this, but I haven't found any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is missing **`SystemConfiguration.framework`**. You will need to add this framework in your project to get rid of this error. To add this in Xcode:

1. Click on your project (at the left top).
2. Click on **Build Phases**.
3. Click **+** button under **Link Binary with Libraries**.
4. Choose `SystemConfiguration.framework` form the list.
5. Add it and compile the project.

[image]